# Why do these two seemingly equivalent expressions evaluate differently?

Tags: python

Why do these two seemingly equivalent expressions evaluate differently?
This works:

```
from random import uniform

def binominal_rv(n,p):
    z=[]
    counter=0
    for i in range(n):
        U=uniform(0,1)
        if  U < p :                #true with probability p
            counter= counter + 1
    return counter
```

But this does not:

```
from random import uniform

def binominal_rv(n,p):
    z=[]
    counter=0
    for i in range(n):
        U=uniform(0,1)
        if  U < p== True :                #true with probability p
            counter= counter + 1
    return counter
```

Whats going on here??? I think that the two if's should be equivalent.

Comment: If you're happy with an answer, please accept it (click the tick next to the post).

Answer (score 3):

It's due to how Python reads expressions.

`U < p == True` is read as `U < p and p == True`. This is clearly not what we want.

As namit said, we can fix this using brackets: `(U < p) == True`. Or just use `U < p`, as in the original code.

---

If you want to learn more, the [Python language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in) explains this feature in detail:

> **Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`,** except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).

Answer (score 2):

change `if  U < p== True :`
to
`if  (U < p)== True :`

lets take an example:

```
In [38]: 2 < 4
Out[38]: True

In [39]: 2 < 4 == True
Out[39]: False

In [40]: (2 < 4) == True
Out[40]: True

In [41]: 4 == True
Out[41]: False

In [42]: 2 < False
Out[42]: False

In [43]: 4 == True
Out[43]: False

In [44]: (4 == True) == 0
Out[44]: True
```

Comment: and `2 < (4==True)` is False, because `0==(4==True)` is True: "The builtins True and False are the only two instances of the class bool.
The class bool is a subclass of the class int, and cannot be subclassed."